# UITextField customization for how text is selected or inserted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm planning to work on a small customization of `UITextField` to change a certain `UI/UX design features`.

I know `UITextField` has a certain inbuilt methods to change the border style, color, etc. But if I wish to make a lot of customization, can someone guide me how I should begin?

Do I need to refer to the UITextField parent class to modify it? Or I will have to make a custom UI object right from the scratch?

EDIT:

The customization I plan on working is how we select/de-select or choose an insertion point for the text in the UITextField.

Comment: Who knows? You have not revealed what design features you're talking about, or what "a lot of customization" means.

Comment: @matt: Apologize, updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going to want to take advantage of the fact that UITextField adopts the UITextInput protocol. You can do that by subclassing UITextField. Alternatively, it might be sufficient for your needs to set up some other class as a delegate of this UITextField - that depends on whether the UITextFieldDelegate notifies you with a sufficiently fine grain that the user is up to something in the text field.